# JQM : Div with data-role page will sit on top of other element

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I've developed an app for ios and android using phonegap. It's a dictionary app and it will display result in multiple tab (the tab is a div, every div will display different content). I use my own code so that only one div is shown at any time. Now I want to include jquerymobile so that I can apply a animation/transition when switching to other div.

So I add the data-role="page" to each div, which I assume will work immediately(like sample code below). But something is not right.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
        <head> 
        <title>Page Title</title> 

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <table id="headergroup">
    <tr><td>
       <input>.........
       <img>.......
    </table>
<wrapper>
    <div data-role="page" id="tab1">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">   
            <p>Page1 content goes here.</p>     
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    .........other div......
    <div data-role="page" id="tabN">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">   
            <p>PageN content goes here.</p>     
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    </wrapper>
    <div id="footer>
     <img .......>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Supposely, my app should display the div(s) in the wrapper only. But the problem is, now my app will display the div with data-role=page in full screen and on top of other element (my app header and footer were not shown).

Is my implementation correct? How do I overcome this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may get by with this on the first page, but on all other pages you are loading in via JQM-Ajax (default), you will only grab what's inside your first(!) div-data-role="page" from the page you are loading. Everything else (table, 2nd, 3rd page-div will not be loaded, because it's outside the page-div.

Have a look at the JQM docs on [page anatomy](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/index.html) and [linking pages](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html).

JQM is based on page-divs, so also in your code the page-div will get most "JQM attention" being set to fullscreen size and of cource hovering above everything else.

To use JQM you will either go with

[Single page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-template.html) layout = page by page
[Multi pape](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/multipage-template.html) layout = multiple pages contained in one document.

Since you are using Phonegap, which I think bundles everything into a single file eventually, you may be better off with multipage. There is also a [subpage](https://github.com/ToddThomson/jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget) widget or [multiview](https://github.com/frequent/multiview), if you need to load documents with multiple "nested pages" from your initial page.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. Previously, I did try the multipage layout, but as you said, it is set to fullscreen which then cover everything else. I'm looking at the multiview plugin, to check whether it's suitabable for me or not... Thanks..